stressed characters not mached after submitting a form in a Java web application
I have a maven project named alpha, compiled with Java 1.8.0_121 and built with Maven 3.3.3.
This project contains three modules:

alphaCommon
alphaBusiness
alphaWeb

Each module has its pom.xml and the artifact alpha-1.0.war is generated under alphaWeb/target. This artifact is then deployed to a local JBoss EAP 7.1.0 server running on Windows 10.
The alpha project uses Struts 1 and Hibernate as frameworks, and the dynamic data are saved and retrieved from a MySQL database (database name: alpha, character set name: latin1, collation name: latin1_swedish_ci) installed to a local MySQL Server, version number 5.0.95.
There is a web page of the project with a form having a input text field named description where stressed characters à, è, é, ì, ò, ù plus other special characters such as \ . - % ^ ' and blank character should be accepted.
On submission of data, a Java method addElement() in a class AjaxServlet is invoked; it gets an HttpServletRequest input parameter, checks the format of the input data and if matches the pattern of the allowed characters, the input data are added in a database table.
The method addElement is the following
private String addElement(HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
            request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ue) {             
            loggerajax.traceLog(loggerajax.INFO, ue.getMessage());
            return "WRONG_CHARACTER_ENCODING";
    }

    String sdescr = request.getParameter("description");
    loggerajax.traceLog(loggerajax.INFO, "description: " + sdescr);
    String patternAllowedCharacters = AlphaParameters.getInstance().getParameter("allowed_characters");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternAllowedCharacters, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sdescr);
    
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
      return "NO_MATCH";
    }
    
    ....
    
    return "ROW_ADDED_IN_TABLE";
}

The instruction
loggerajax.traceLog(...);

creates and adds in a custom JBoss logfile named alpha.log, the string passed as an input parameter, with INFO level.
The strings returned from the addElement method

"WRONG_CHARACTER_ENCODING"
"NO_MATCH"
"ROW_ADDED_IN_TABLE"

result in a specific message on the web.
The instruction
String patternAllowedCharacters = AlphaParameters.getInstance().getParameter("allowed characters");

extracts from a table of the alpha database, named tbl_parameters, the following string
[\\\.\-\s%A-Za-z0-9\ò\à\ì\è\é\ù\'\^]*
and assigns it to the patternAllowedCharacters String variable.
If sdescr contains a character not found in the above pattern, matcher.matches() returns false and addElement returns
"NO_MATCH"; otherwise, the script goes on and "ROW_ADDED_IN_TABLE" is returned, which means successful operation.
Unfortunately, the stressed characters, despite being in the pattern of the allowed ones, aren't matched! I googled around and seems as if the problem is due to a bad character encoding, and UTF-8 should be used. I found several solutions which I implemented all together:

placed the tag <meta charset="UTF-8"/> at the top of all the JSP pages

set the character encoding to UTF-8 to the HttpServletRequest request variable (see request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") in the try block of the addElement method)

added in the struts-config.xml (located at alpha/alphaWeb/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF) the following plugin
<plug-in className="org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn">    
    <set-property property="contextConfigLocation" value="/WEB-INF/web-character-encoding.xml"/></plug-in>


placed the file web-character-encoding.xml under alpha/alphaWeb/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF with the following bean defined

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

       <bean id="characterEncodingFilter" class="org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter">
           <property name="encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
           <property name="forceEncoding" value="true"/>
       </bean>
       </beans>


added in the web.xml (located at alpha/alphaWeb/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF) the following filter
<filter>
<filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>   </filter>       <filter-mapping>
<filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>   </filter-mapping>


added in the pom.xml of the alphaWeb module the following
dependencies
 <dependency>        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>         <version>2.5.4</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>  </dependency>   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>       <version>2.5.4</version>
 </dependency>   <dependency>        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>         <version>2.5.4</version>
 </dependency>



(note: unfortunately I am not allowed to upgrade the version of the project and all of its Maven dependencies, nor changing the charset or the collation of the database and tables!)
I still get "NO_MATCH" as a result of the addElement() method when I put in the input field text a stressed character. Any other character in the pattern is successful!
I checked out the server.log, but I get no error; in the alpha.log file, the value of sdescr is the following:
description: ?

The file standalone.xml in the JBoss server, has the following configuration for the alpha.log file:
<profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <encoding value="UTF-8"/>
            <target name="console"/>
        </console-handler>
        <file-handler name="ALPHA_FILE">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <encoding value="UTF-8"/>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="alpha.log"/>
        </file-handler>
        <periodic-size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <rotate-size value="3072k"/>
            <max-backup-index value="3"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-size-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="INFO"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.hibernate" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.struts" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.springframework" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
    
    ...
</profile>

Additional information:
The front end is like the image below

in the field labelled Description (red rectangle) I put a sequence of all stressed characters, which are supposed to be valid. When I click on the Submit image (red arrow), I get the following result

The following are the snippets containing the HTML code of the form and the JavaScript function refreshTabNew which sends the form input data (plus other parameters) by AJAX call.
function refreshTabNew(scode_record, scode_app,  type, id_elem, idform) {

    var call = "method=refreshTabNew";
    call = call + "&scode_record=" + scode_record;
    call = call + "&scode_app=" + scode_app;
    call = call + "&type=" + type;
    call = call + "&id_element=" + id_elem;

    var descriptor = "[form='"+idform+"']";
    var form = $(descriptor);
    var x = form.serializeArray();
    $.each(x, function (i, field) {
        console.log("form field name: " + field.name + "; field value: " + field.value);

        if (field.name == "area") {
            call = call + "&area=" + field.value;
        }
        if (field.name == "code1") {
            call = call + "&code1=" + field.value;
        }
        if (field.name == "function_code") {
            call = call + "&function_code=" + field.value;
        }
        if (field.name == "description") {
            call = call + "&description=" + escape(field.value);
        }

    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "/alpha/ajaxServlet",
        type: 'POST',
        data : call,
        dataType: "html",
        cache: true,
        beforeSend: function(){
            console.log(call);
            document.getElementById("workareaManager").innerHTML = "<table width=\"100%\"><tr><td  width=\"100%\" align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" colspan=\"15\" style=\"font: italic 12px verdana, 'Bitstream Vera Sans', helvetica, arial; color: #800000;\"><img src=\"./images/indicator.gif\">&nbsp;Loading data ...</td></tr></table>";
        },

        success: function(response){
            console.log("Ajax call refreshTabNew successful!");
            document.getElementById("workareaManager").innerHTML = response;

        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

}

<form id="editRow"></form>
<table valign="top" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="list_row_sheet">
        <td width="6%" align="center" colspan="2" nowrap="">
            <a form="editRow" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getNewCodes(1,'0100', '0001',  'X100-0100-K-000002', document.editRow.type.value); return false;">
                <img src="./images/add_row.png" border="0" title="Generate new codes"></a>&nbsp;
            <a form="editRow" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="if(checkRow('editRow', 1)===false) {return false;} else {refreshTabNew('X100-0100-K-000002','0001',1, 0, 'editRow'); return false; }">
                <img src="./images/save_sheet.png" border="0" title="Save data"></a>
        </td>
        <td width="5%">
            <input form="editRow" type="text" size="7" name="area" title="proprietary area" value="" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td width="5%">
            <input form="editRow" type="text" name="code1" title="code n. 1" size="7" value="" readonly=""></td>
        <td width="6%">
            <input form="editRow" type="text" name="function_code" title="Function code" size="12" value="" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td width="17%" nowrap="">
            <input form="editRow" type="text" size="30" autocomplete="off" id="complete-field" maxlength="300"
                title="Function code description" name="description" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


Can you make that instead the following and post a failing example please? loggerajax.traceLog(loggerajax.INFO, "description: " + sdescr.codePoints().mapToObj(c ->"%02x".formatted(c)).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));

I appreciate the effort you put in describing the issue but it seems too complex and it is not clear if the issue is just with the pattern matching. Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Unrelated to the issue, with versions like Spring 2.5.4 (released in 2008!) that is a security vulnerability nightmare.

Unfortunately, character matching is not quite that simple these days. You need to run the following to see why: String[] twins = { "Fr\u00E8re", "Fre\u0300re" };System.out.println(Arrays.toString(twins));System.out.println(twins[0].equals(twins[1]));

@g00se My project is compiled and run in java 8. The "formatted" String method is of Java 11. Anyway, I replaced loggerajax.traceLog(loggerajax.INFO, "description: " + descr) with  loggerajax.traceLog(loggerajax.INFO, "description: " + sdescr.codePoints().mapToObj(c ->"%02x".format(String.valueOf(c))).collect(Collectors.joining(" "))); then placed the string à ù è é ò ì in the input text field of the form; after submit, in the logfile, I see the following statement:
description: 65533 32 65533 32 65533 32 65533 32 65533 32 65533

Yes, that was truly garbage for the servlet. What's the front end for the client looking like (the html)?

@aled unfortunately, reproducing the issue with a minimal code is quite difficult. I added extra information showing the form when stressed characteras are put in the form input field and what is diplayed after submittng the data, hoping it can be a bit helpful

@g00se I added in the question two pictures as an Extra information, showing the front end before and after submitting all of the stressed characters

That's good, but we should see the html code of that form (assuming it's yours)

You didn't post anything. btw, are you getting that WRONG_CHARACTER_ENCODING returned?

@g00se sorry, keyboard problems. I don't get WRONG_CHARACTER_ENCODING, but NO_MATCH

Ah OK. Yes, I should have known as the parameter is showing 'replacement' characters which wouldn't have been reached. But.. I still see no html form

Try adding in to that Ajax contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",

@g00se unfortunately, I still get question marks in the description field....I forgot saying that, in the console.log, the description is well formatted, whether I add the contentType or not ...the problem is all inside the addElement() method

Try something wild. Change that to Windows-1252

@g00se it doesn't work but I solved in another way! I worked on javascript side: when creating the querystring parameter=value I added
description=encodeURIComponent(field.value).replaceAll("'", "%27")
instead of
description=escape(field.value)
leaving everything else of what I implemented.
I'll write this solution in my question and change the title in Solved.
Thank you very much for your suggestion!

I have rolled back your last edit. If you managed to solve your own problem, then post an Answer, don't the solution to your Question, and don't add things like "SOLVED" to your Question title. Resolution of a question is signaled by accepting an answer (in the case of a self-answer, there may be a timeout before you can accept).

As an aside, why are you using software that is years out of date? Beside the Spring version already mentioned, Java 8 update 121 is ancient, as is Maven 3.3.3 and MySQL 5.0.95 and Struts 1. Doesn't your employer care about security?

@MarkRotteveel about posting the answer and not self-answer, you are right. Regarding the old dated software, my hands are tied! I am aware that I'm working with software and framework version belonging to prehistory, but it's not even up to my employer taking the decision of upgrading all!
